# Using strncpy to copy a char* pointing to an array of names

Tags: c++, strncpy

I have an array of names test1,test2...
I need to make new array with only filterd names. I am bound to use char*.

```
const char* names[randomLength] = {"test1","test2","test3"...};
```

I need to create a new array with partial names in the array

```
const char* filteredNames[randomLength-values];

strncpy(*filteredNames,*names,sizeof(a)/sizeof(char)-values);
```

I am expecting filteredNames to be test1,test2.
But this is causing segmentation fault. Please help me fix this and alos suggest better approach.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Answer by @Jabberwocky works. Thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomLength-values; i++)
  filteredNames[i] = names[i];
```

Comment by @mch doesn't work in cases like

```
void test(char**& filterednames)
{
...
...
memcpy(names,filterednames,sizeof(filterednames));
...
}
```

This results in a segmentation fault. Please point out my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: You do not want to copy strings, you want to copy the pointers. `memcpy(filteredNames, names, sizeof filteredNames);` should do the job.

Comment: I didn't really look into your question, but concerning `strncpy`: read the [documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) very closely, especially the part that explains what happens if the source string is longer than the value of the 3rd parameter you pass to `strncpy`..

Comment: Please define "filtered names" and/or "partial names". Also show explicitly what `for (int i; i < ...; i++) printf("%s\n", filteredNames[i]);` should print. [Edit] your question any clarify.

Comment: @OP You have three `C++` tags on your question.  Since you did this, why are you not using `std::string` or `std::string_view`?

Comment: That's the same as `strncpy(filteredNames[0] ,names[0], sizeof(a)/sizeof(char)-values);` and has undefined behaviour since `filteredNames[0]` is a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want `strncpy` here but your want something similar to this:

```
const char* names[randomLength] = {"test1","test2","test3"...};
...
int value = 2;
const char* filteredNames[randomLength-values];
...
for (int i = 0; i < randomLength-values; i++)
  filteredNames[i] = names[i];  // copy only the pointer
```

Be aware that `const char* filteredNames[foo];` when `foo` is not a compile time constant (VLAs, or variable length arrays) is not standard C++, but an extension for some C++ compilers.